# Selenium webdriver with python to scrape dynamic page cannot find element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scraper

So there are a lot of questions that have been asked around dynamic content scraping on stackoverflow, and I went through all of these, but all the solutions suggested did not work for the following problem:

### Context:

- Using Selenium webdriver with python
- I mostly used this resource: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/page-objects.html regarding the Python.org example.
- **Page to scrape:** http://propertymap.sfplanning.org/

### Issue:

I have not been able to access any of the DOM elements on this page. Note if I could get some hints on how to access the search bar, and the search button, that would be a great start. [See page to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOipY.png)
What I want in the end, is to go through a list of addresses, launch the search, and copy the information displayed on the right hand side of the screen.

I have tried the following:

- Changed the browser for webdriver (from Chrome to Firefox)
- Added waiting time for the page to load

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "addressInput")))
  except:
      print "address input not found"
  ```
- Tried to access the item by ID, XPATH, NAME, TAG NAME, etc., nothing worked.

**Questions**

- What else could I try that I have not so far (using Selenium webdriver)?
- Are some websites really impossible to scrape? (I don't think that the city used an algorithm to generate any random DOM everytime I re-load the page).

Comment: find the search field with one of the find_by_* methods, send Keys.ENTER

Comment: The problem was that it could not find the elements... not about how to send keys.

Comment: your question had 2 parts: "if I could get some hints on how to access the search bar, *and* the search button"... I supplied the various methods to look for (`find_by_*`) to locate an element.  (the accepted answer chose `find_element_by_id`).  Also note, hitting enter to bypass an element lookup and simulated click tends to be faster and more reliable in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this url `http://50.17.237.182/PIM/` to get the source:

```
In [73]: from selenium import webdriver


In [74]: dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

In [75]: dr.get("http://50.17.237.182/PIM/")

In [76]: print(dr.find_element_by_id("addressInput"))
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f4d21c80950>
```

If you look at the source returned, there is a frame attribute with that src url:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>San Francisco Property Information Map </title>
  <META name="description" content="Public access to useful property information and resources at the click of a mouse"><META name="keywords" content="san francisco, property, information, map, public, zoning, preservation, projects, permits, complaints, appeals">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://50.17.237.182/PIM" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 02 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

Thanks to @Alecxe, the simplest method it to use `dr.switch_to.frame(0)`:

```
In [77]: dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

In [78]: dr.get("http://propertymap.sfplanning.org/")

In [79]:  dr.switch_to.frame(0)  

In [80]: print(dr.find_element_by_id("addressInput"))
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f4d21c80190>
```

If you visit `http://50.17.237.182/PIM/` in your browser, you will see exactly the same as `propertymap.sfplanning.org/`, the only difference is you have full access to the elements using the former.

If you want to input a value and click the search box, it is something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver


dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get("http://propertymap.sfplanning.org/")

dr.switch_to.frame(0)

dr.find_element_by_id("addressInput").send_keys("whatever")
dr.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search button']").click()
```

But if you want to pull data, you may find querying using the url an easier option, you will get some json back from the query.

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to switch to the `iframe`: `driver.switch_to.frame(0)`, right?

Comment: @alecxe, yep, that would be easier :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: thank you so much, this is beautiful- I am mad at myself because I never thought about looking at that. I've spent 2 full days on that...

Comment: @AudreyBascoul, you're welcome, the image is not the best at the end  but if you open firebig or chrome dev tools and monitor the network requests you will get a clearer picture of what is happening.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks! Sometimes I use Fiddler. Good note on using the url to send the query :)